Kivy 2.3 VideoPlayer Android Crash
I'm trying to create video .apk which includes Video or VideoPlayer.
main.py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer
import os
os.environ["KIVY_VIDEO"] = "ffpyplayer"
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.utils import platform

kv = """
MainLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Is file Exist?"
            on_release: root.checkFile()
        Label:
            id: l1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: "Load 1.mp4 to Video & VideoPlayer"
            on_release: root.loadmp4()
        Label:
            id: l2
            text: "Waiting to Load File"
    BoxLayout:
        Video:
            id: vd
        VideoPlayer:
            id: vdp
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: vdb
            text: "Video Load file first"
            on_release: root.playVideo()
            disabled: True
        Button:
            text: "VideoPlayer Load file first"
            id: vdpb
            on_release: root.playVideoPlayer()
            disabled: True
    BoxLayout:  
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: "use gstplayer"
                on_release: root.setKivyVideoEnviron("gstreamer")
            Button:
                text: "use ffmpeg"
                on_release: root.setKivyVideoEnviron("gstplayer")
            Button:
                text: "use ffpyplayer"
                on_release: root.setKivyVideoEnviron("ffpyplayer")
            
        Button:
            text: "Show Kivy Video Providers"
            on_release: root.showKivyVideoOptions()
        Label:
            id: log
            text: "Logs"
"""

class MainLayout(BoxLayout):
    def vpwPlay(self,*args):
        self.ids.vpw.state = "play"
    def showKivyVideoOptions(self,*args):
        App.get_running_app().askpermission() #also check read&write permission
        self.ids.log.text = str(kivy.kivy_options["video"])
    def setKivyVideoEnviron(self,env,*args):
        try:
            os.environ["KIVY_VIDEO"] = env
        except Exception as err:
            self.ids.log.text = str(err)

    def checkFile(self, *args):
        try:
            file_exists = os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "1.mp4"))
            self.ids.l1.text = "File exist: " + str(file_exists)
        except Exception as err:
            self.ids.log.text = str(err)

    def loadmp4(self, *args):
        try:
            file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "1.mp4")
            self.ids.vd.source = file_path
            self.ids.vdp.source = file_path
            self.ids.l2.text = "Loaded file: " + file_path
            self.ids.vdb.text = "[VIDEO]\nPlay Video"
            self.ids.vdb.disabled = False
            self.ids.vdpb.text = "[VIDEOPLAYER]\nPlay Video"
            self.ids.vdpb.disabled = False
        except Exception as err:
            self.ids.log.text = str(err)

    def playVideo(self, *args):
        try:
            self.ids.vd.state = 'play'
        except Exception as err:
            self.ids.log.text = str(err)

    def playVideoPlayer(self, *args):
        try:
            self.ids.vdp.state = 'play'
        except Exception as err:
            self.ids.log.text = str(err)
class MyApp(App):
    def askpermission(self,*args):
        if platform == "android":
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
            request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

buildozer.spec:
[app]
title = Test Video APK
package.name = myapp.videotestetststeste
package.domain = org.testtestestest
source.dir = .
source.include_exts =
version = 0.1
requirements = python3,kivy==2.3.0,olefile,ffpyplayer,ffpyplayer_codecs
orientation = portrait
osx.python_version = 3.11
osx.kivy_version = 2.3.0
fullscreen = 1
android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;maxSdkVersion=18)

Log:
07-31 02:01:02.992 15263 15263 V pythonutil: Loading library: python3.11
07-31 02:01:03.038 15263 15263 V pythonutil: Loading library: main
07-31 02:01:03.042 15263 15263 V pythonutil: Loaded everything!
07-31 02:01:03.146 15263 15302 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
07-31 02:01:03.146 15263 15302 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
07-31 02:01:03.147 15263 15302 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
07-31 02:01:03.147 15263 15302 I python  : /data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app
07-31 02:01:03.170 15263 15302 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
07-31 02:01:03.170 15263 15302 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
07-31 02:01:03.170 15263 15302 I python  : calculated paths to be...
07-31 02:01:03.170 15263 15302 I python  : /data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
07-31 02:01:03.170 15263 15302 I python  : set wchar paths...
07-31 02:01:03.194 15263 15263 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:56907): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/zlib.cpython-311.so" dev="sda15" ino=900967 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste
07-31 02:01:03.221 15263 15302 I python  : Initialized python
07-31 02:01:03.221 15263 15302 I python  : AND: Init threads
07-31 02:01:03.222 15263 15302 I python  : testing python print redirection
07-31 02:01:03.223 15263 15302 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
07-31 02:01:03.223 15263 15302 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/apex/com.android.art/bin:/system_ext/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'ANDROID_ART_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.art', 'ANDROID_I18N_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.i18n', 'ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.tzdata', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-icu4j.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/framework-atb-backward-compatibility.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/telephony-ext.jar:/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar:/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar:/apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/updatable-media.jar:/apex/com.android.mediaprovider/javalib/framework-mediaprovider.jar:/apex/com.android.os.statsd/javalib/framework-statsd.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/framework-permission.jar:/apex/com.android.sdkext/javalib/framework-sdkextensions.jar:/apex/com.android.wifi/javalib/framework-wifi.jar:/apex/com.android.tethering/javalib/framework-tethering.jar', 'DEX2OATBOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-icu4j.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/framework-atb-backward-compatibility.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/telephony-ext.jar:/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar:/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/apex/com.android.permission/javalib/service-permission.jar:/apex/com.android.wifi/javalib/service-wifi.jar:/apex/com.android.ipsec/javalib/android.net.ipsec.ike.jar', 'DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote': '18', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_usap_pool_primary': '23', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app:/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/lib', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'P4A_BOOTSTRAP': 'SDL2', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python', 'P4A_IS_WINDOWED': 'False', 'KIVY_ORIENTATION': 'Portrait', 'P4A_NUMERIC_VERSION': 'None', 'P4A_MINSDK': '21', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C.UTF-8'})
07-31 02:01:03.223 15263 15302 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
07-31 02:01:03.223 15263 15302 I python  : AND: Ran string
07-31 02:01:03.223 15263 15302 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
07-31 02:01:03.284 15263 15263 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:56908): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_typing.cpython-311.so" dev="sda15" ino=900949 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste
07-31 02:01:03.334 15263 15263 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:56909): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/math.cpython-311.so" dev="sda15" ino=900956 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste
07-31 02:01:03.364 15263 15263 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:56912): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_opcode.cpython-311.so" dev="sda15" ino=900928 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste
07-31 02:01:03.389 15263 15302 I python  : [ERROR  ] Error when copying logo directory
07-31 02:01:03.389 15263 15302 I python  : Traceback (most recent call last):
07-31 02:01:03.390 15263 15302 I python  :   File "/mnt/KivyVideoAPK/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp.videotestetststeste/arm64-v8a/kivy/__init__.py", line 372, in <module>
07-31 02:01:03.390 15263 15302 I python  :   File "/mnt/KivyVideoAPK/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/shutil.py", line 561, in copytree
07-31 02:01:03.390 15263 15302 I python  :   File "/mnt/KivyVideoAPK/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/shutil.py", line 515, in _copytree
07-31 02:01:03.390 15263 15302 I python  : shutil.Error: [('/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-128.png', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-128.png', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-128.png'"), ('/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-16.png', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-16.png', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-16.png'"), ('/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-24.png', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-24.png', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-24.png'"), ('/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-256.png', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-256.png', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-256.png'"), ('/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-32.png', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-32.png', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-32.png'"), ('/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-48.png', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-48.png', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-48.png'"), ('/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-512.png', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-512.png', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-512.png'"), ('/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-64.ico', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-64.ico', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-64.ico'"), ('/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-64.png', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-64.png', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-64.png'"), ('/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon'")]
07-31 02:01:03.399 15263 15302 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 27)
07-31 02:01:03.400 15263 15302 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
07-31 02:01:03.400 15263 15302 I python  : [DEBUG  ] [Config      ] Upgrading from 0 to 1
07-31 02:01:03.403 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_24-07-31_0.txt
07-31 02:01:03.405 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.3.0
07-31 02:01:03.406 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
07-31 02:01:03.406 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.5 (main, Jul 31 2024, 01:30:29) [Clang 14.0.6 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb0
07-31 02:01:03.406 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
07-31 02:01:03.407 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
07-31 02:01:03.407 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
07-31 02:01:04.354 15263 15263 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:56934): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/binascii.cpython-311.so" dev="sda15" ino=900913 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste
07-31 02:01:04.374 15263 15263 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:56935): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_contextvars.cpython-311.so" dev="sda15" ino=900911 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste
07-31 02:01:04.384 15263 15263 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:56936): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_asyncio.cpython-311.so" dev="sda15" ino=900869 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste
07-31 02:01:04.424 15263 15263 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:56937): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/_event.so" dev="sda15" ino=901266 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c221,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste
07-31 02:01:04.445 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 195 symbols loaded
07-31 02:01:04.602 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.3.2
07-31 02:01:04.603 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer (img_pil ignored)
07-31 02:01:04.907 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [VideoFFPy   ] Using ffpyplayer 4.3.2
07-31 02:01:04.908 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: ffpyplayer(['video_ffmpeg'] ignored)
07-31 02:01:04.940 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
07-31 02:01:05.020 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
07-31 02:01:05.026 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
07-31 02:01:05.026 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@0502.0 (GIT@d4cfdf3, Ic907de5ed0, 1601055299) (Date:09/25/20)'>
07-31 02:01:05.027 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
07-31 02:01:05.027 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 610'>
07-31 02:01:05.027 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
07-31 02:01:05.028 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
07-31 02:01:05.028 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
07-31 02:01:05.082 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
07-31 02:01:05.083 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
07-31 02:01:05.084 15263 15302 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading <1.mp4>
07-31 02:01:05.087 15263 15302 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
07-31 02:01:05.087 15263 15302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
07-31 02:01:05.604 15331 15331 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 000000000001539c  /data/data/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.so
07-31 02:01:05.604 15331 15331 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 00000000002c82b8  /data/app/~~s0lBApATuUpzckMd1_r55w==/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste-PxUqzVwevgRc14pJJJu1eQ==/lib/arm64/libpython3.11.so (_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+2052)
07-31 02:01:05.604 15331 15331 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 00000000002c78e4  /data/app/~~s0lBApATuUpzckMd1_r55w==/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste-PxUqzVwevgRc14pJJJu1eQ==/lib/arm64/libpython3.11.so (PyEval_EvalCode+268)
07-31 02:01:05.604 15331 15331 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 00000000003187e8  /data/app/~~s0lBApATuUpzckMd1_r55w==/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste-PxUqzVwevgRc14pJJJu1eQ==/lib/arm64/libpython3.11.so (_PyRun_SimpleFileObject+1188)
07-31 02:01:05.604 15331 15331 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 00000000003190ac  /data/app/~~s0lBApATuUpzckMd1_r55w==/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste-PxUqzVwevgRc14pJJJu1eQ==/lib/arm64/libpython3.11.so (PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags+60)

Code works on windows&linux side but fails on Android. Can't figure out what is wrong with these last 5 rows of LOG.

There's nothing wrong with the last 4 (or 5) lines in the log - they're there to provide debugging information. You should be more concerned with the lines containing [ERROR  ].

Are you sure ? Console call last 5 lines as "F" isn't it meaning Fatal Error ?

It seems like there is a permissions error related to copying assets: 07-31 02:01:03.390 15263 15302 I python  : shutil.Error: [('/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-128.png', '/data/user/0/org.testtestestest.myapp.videotestetststeste/files/app/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-128.png', "[Errno 13] Permission denied:...

I don't think it causes t he main problem because application can stay alive after these errors. Updated code for step-by-step check. I'm wondering that im using ffpyplayer==4.5.1 on Windows side but buildozer downloads ffpyplayer==4.3.2. I'll try to force buildozer to use mine.

on Android side, SDL_AUDIODRIVER fails and returns these errors.
Solution: REF
import os
os.environ["SDL_AUDIODRIVER"] = "android"

trigger this lines before main return starts.
